# SQL Server management studio 2005 does not change data type after creating table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, constraints

'tblEmployee' table
- Unable to create index 'PK_*tblEmployee*_72C60C4A'.
Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'tblEmployee'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming because you might have the third column for `NULL` left `checked`. Or might be you are altering this table , having data and the column you are trying to make `PK` has null value,somewhere.

Kindly note before converting a column to `PK`, ensure it is not null and it has `unique values(in case of alteration)`

Comment: What you are doing and when you are getting this error. Kindly elaborate the steps

Comment: i m changing data type of my column from sql 2005 then error comes when i save the

Comment: Check if your table contains records and that column has  null inside

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that you are trying to add a column that is nullable ("Allow Nulls" is ticked) as part of a Primary key which is not allowed.

*You need to change the definition of the column to not allow nulls*...however if any of the values in the column are already NULL then you will need to UPDATE the table to provide some value for them first and then you can untick "Allow Nulls" and add this column as part of a primary key.

e.g suppose your existing key column is EmployeeID and you want to add DepartmentID as a part of that key, but the values in it are null and for some reason you cannot remove the data that's in the table (although I personally recommend that you do this, it's easier to change keys and whatnot with no data in the table!)

- UPDATE Employees set DepartmentID=row_number() over (order by EmployeeID ASC) --for example
- Then untick "Allow Nulls" in the table designer and Save (if it doesn't allow you to save because the table must be recreated to save it, then go to Tools->Options->Designers and uncheck the "prevent saving changes that requite table re-creation" box.
- Finally add your column to the PK and save the table and then you'll need to go back and put the *real* values for DepartmentID into the table.

Obviously whatever value you choose to update the column with will still need to yield a unique key when combined with the other PK columns...

Comment: but the option prevent saving changes that requite table re-creation" box is not show sql server management studio 2005

Comment: @ShivNarwariya - are you 100% certain? On sSql 2005 it may be under "Table and Database Designers" not just "Designers". I'm afraid I don't have Sql 2005 to check...in any case if it's realy really not there then you will have to ship all that table data into a temp table and update it there, then trash the original table, make your pk changes and copy the temp data back in.